# Noting and quoting breaktime hours

Tags: break-time

So after doing some reading [here on SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18138/how-many-hours-do-you-expect-to-clock-in-a-40-hour-week), it seems to be mostly acceptable for an employee to be productive for only 6 hours of his 8 hours workday.

However, how should one write down these hours in the company's backlog? A lot of companies have their employees write down their activites from hour-to-hour in a backlog. How should "unproductive" time (could be reading SE, toilet breaks, checking facebook, etc) be noted in these logs?

Adding the unproductive time to preceeding or subsequent tasks seems like the easiest thing to do, but this becomes troublesome if you are working with an hour quota for a client. Should this unproductive time / breaktimes also be included in the quotation for a client?

**Is it common practice to pre-calculate the amount of unproductive time during work-hours and add this in quotations for clients of the company?**

Comment: @JoeStrazzere You're right, it's very company specific. I have clarified my question though for the 2nd part, which is less company-specific.

Comment: ANd much of that time is spent doing actual work, just not your direct work. Things like filling in timesheets, attending HR meetings, reading emails, etc. come to mind. It isn't 2 hours of slack time.

Comment: "Administrative"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "Unproductive" time should not be recorded unless a project code is specifically provided for that purpose.  If you have gaps in time accounted for and they are not okay with that, the system is doing what it is supposed to, identifying a problem.
2. Very short breaks can be considered part of overhead for the project that you are working on but if they start bloating your project time you are taking too many of them (again, that is part of what tracking is supposed to accomplish).
3. As to whether you should include this time in the quote for the client, sure, if you intend to take it.  If this causes your quote to be so large that the client declines the contract, it is market forces at work and all is well.  If, however, the quote was created by someone else I think you can be fairly safe in assuming that no unproductive time was included in the quote.

I think perhaps you are confusing "personal" time (potty breaks, Facebook, web surfing for pleasure, lunch) with administrative time (reports, research, meetings, client support, etc).  In the case of administrative time it is up to the employer to decide if it will be broken out of the project that it supports, or is rolled into it.  I can certainly see a 25% administrative budget, and that would be included in the quote by an experienced manager.

---

### "Acceptable"

According to bosses or employees?  I can't imagine any manager that I've ever had being okay with 25% of your time being spent on potty breaks, Facebook and other personal pursuits.  If they are paying you for 8 hours a day you should be working 8 hours.  It is understood that occasionally there will be short breaks to take care of hygiene, personal calls, etc, but they certainly should not be taking up 25% of your time.

Time spent in meetings, doing work related research, administrative, etc should either be billed to administrative (or whatever project your employer provides for this purpose) or it should be billed to the project that you are doing research or having meetings for.

And if you are only working 8 hours in a day, you need to find out if you are allowed to count lunch as part of that 8 hours, otherwise you should be putting in the extra time if you want to take a lunch.

Of course, you may have a very generous boss who allows for a more liberal free time policy, but unless you specifically ask him, you should not assume this to be the case.

In my field (programming), managers calculate the amount of time necessary and then add in an extra 50% because there are always specifications that didn't get added or assumptions that prove incorrect or emergencies that come up.  They do *not* take "free time" into account.  I don't know if this is the case in other fields.

If you are the person writing up the quotes and you pad for free time and your boss (or the client) is okay with the time you are quoting, that's a different story.  I know people who are brilliant coders and they can get the same amount of work done in half the time.  One might suggest that because they can do the job in half the time they should be entitled to take the "saved" time as free time.  But then you have to ask yourself...are they being paid more than an "average" coder?  If so, they should be producing more.

It's all fairly fuzzy in theory, but the specifics are something that need to be explicitly discussed with whoever you report to.  If you are reluctant to do so, it may be a sign that you know what you are doing will be unacceptable to him.  In this case you need to be honest with yourself and decide what your work ethic is going to be.

Answer (score 3):

**Six hours of productive time does not mean two hours of killing time.**

When people talk about "six hours of productive time a day", the other time goes on stuff that isn't actually producing finished product, but is nonetheless a part of working. The two hours would included status meetings, filling in timesheets, attending compulsory company training, setting up the new internal wiki, chatting with the sales guy (because that's what they like to do, and you never know when they might say something important), and yes, the occasional bathroom break.

If you are spending many hours a day on Facebook then you are not working by any definition.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, it seems I did get the wrong idea about what exactly is viewed under this "unproductive time".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is appropriate to note "downtime".  For starters it is usually in small increments.  A "potty break" may only be 10 minutes.

When I worked for a defense contractor we had to note all our hours to the half hour.  We used to joke that our morning coffee break was a 14 1/2 minute break.  This was because anything over 15 minutes was rounded up.

So keep your "downtime" to a minimum, spread it out, and focus on your overall productivity.  Do what you need to keep that level high and you should not have any problems.